# Display an error message on an HTML form, then, remove this message after user corrects error

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to build a simple application using HTML5 and basic JavaScript. I have it working, but I'm having trouble doing a simple thing (at least simple in other languages I've used). Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
            <title>JS Test</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
        </head>

        <script>
            function isTrackValid(track_a, track_b) {
                if(track_a > 200.0 || track_a < 0.0) {
                    return "Number must be between 0 BPM and 200 BPM";
                }
                if(track_b > 200.0 || track_b < 0.0) {
                    return "Number must be between 0 BPM and 200 BPM";
                }
                return "";
            }

            function calculate(track_a, track_b) {
                if(track_a > track_b) {
                    return ((track_a - track_b) / track_a) * 100;
                } else if(track_a < track_b) {
                    return ((track_a - track_b) / track_b) * 100;
                } else {
                    return 0.0;
                }
            }

            function main() {
                track_a = input_a.valueAsNumber;
                track_b = input_b.valueAsNumber;

                var message = isTrackValid(track_a, track_b);
                if(message !== "") {
                    $('#error_message').text(message);
                } else {
                    var result = calculate(track_a, track_b);
                    return result.toFixed(2);
                }
            }
        </script>
        <body>
            <header>
                <h1>JS Test</h1>
            </header>
            <form onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value=eval(main());">
                Track A: <input name="input_a" id="input_a" type="number" min="0.0" max="200.0" placeholder="Track A"><br/>
                Track B: <input name="input_b" id="input_b" type="number" min="0.0" max="200.0" placeholder="Track B"><br/>
                <br />
                <div id="error_message"></div>
                Output: <output name="o" step="0.01" for="a b"></output>
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

What I want to have, is for my `<output>` to show up if the user enters a number between 0 and 200. This `output` will have the correct answer calculated from the javascript above. If the user enters a negative number, or a number > 200, then I want the error to be put in the `<output>` field.

With the current code (and the `<div>` as a result of an answer on StackOverflow), when an error occurs, it goes above the `Output`. However, when the user enters a valid number, this error stays there and never goes away.

I was wondering if I could make the error go away? Or is there something I can do to just have it go to `Output` if it is invalid?

Comment: @GopsAB Doing this via JSFiddle seems to display no error: https://jsfiddle.net/jthjzsjx/

Comment: did you include jquery for _ $('#error_message').text(message);_ ?

Comment: @Alex Are you using **`JQuery`**? And if so have you added?

Comment: @Niklesh :o I didn't even realize it was JQuery. I originally asked a question on StackOverflow about error handling with just javascript.

Comment: I know there wasn't (might be there now) an <OUTPUT> HTML command. So I'm going to say that should be a DIV (ie: <div id="output"></div>). You can then either show/hide the DIV or you can move it to something like -5000,-5000 when you don't want to see it.  Also, you would need a z-index set to something other than zero(0) which is the layer everything else is on. (ie: z-index:1 would overlay the rest of the web page.)

Answer (score 0):

> You are not removing `error` message if value is valid. Also note, instead of using `eval`, you can bind events using `JavaScript Event Binding` on `[type = number]` elements.

Try this:

```js
function isTrackValid(track_a, track_b) {
  if (track_a > 200.0 || track_a < 0.0) {
    return "Number must be between 0 BPM and 200 BPM";
  }
  if (track_b > 200.0 || track_b < 0.0) {
    return "Number must be between 0 BPM and 200 BPM";
  }
  return "";
}

function calculate(track_a, track_b) {
  if (track_a > track_b) {
    return ((track_a - track_b) / track_a) * 100;
  } else if (track_a < track_b) {
    return ((track_a - track_b) / track_b) * 100;
  } else {
    return 0.0;
  }
}

function main() {
  track_a = input_a.valueAsNumber;
  track_b = input_b.valueAsNumber;
  var message = isTrackValid(track_a, track_b);
  if (message !== "") {
    $('#error_message').text(message);
  } else {
    $('#error_message').text(message);
    var result = calculate(track_a, track_b);
    return result.toFixed(2);
  }
}

var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[type="number"]');
[].forEach.call(elems, function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('input', main);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return false">
  Track A:
  <input name="input_a" id="input_a" type="number" min="0.0" max="200.0" placeholder="Track A">
  <br/>Track B:
  <input name="input_b" id="input_b" type="number" min="0.0" max="200.0" placeholder="Track B">
  <br/>
  <br />
  <div id="error_message"></div>
  Output:
  <output name="o" step="0.01" for="a b"></output>
</form>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/netc4ubf/)